# Sort numeric values VBA

Tags: excel, vba, database, sorting

I have data. Can be in list or just in rows and colums or anything really.

I have data entries like 10, 1010, 11, 111,2,201,3210, 300100 etc 6 numbers is max.
I would like to have data be sorted

10
1010
11
111
2
201
300100
3210

And not like

2
10
11
111
201
1010
3210
300100

Any neat way do to this. Can make it work with filters, so guess I need some code and cant figure it out.

Can make it work with filters if i add "." or something between every number. Then just add filter ?.?.?.?.?.? and sort accending. Havent even tried any code.

Comment: You make your question to vague, please give us the example you are dealing with so we can give you a good answer. "I have data. Can be in list or just in rows and colums or anything really."  Is not helping us to really understand what you are dealing wiht.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No VBA, but formulae; you could try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=SORTBY(A1:A8,LEFT(A1:A8&"00000",6))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the values in VBA, you can sort them alphabetically by forcing them to be strings and then using the `<` or `>` operator. Variant values and numbers will need to be converted to strings with `CStr` or an equivalent operation. You could also pass the values into a `String` variable, which will force it to become a `String` value.

```vb
Sub Example()
    Const VALUES As String = "2 10 11 111 201 1010 3210 300100"
    
    'Value Type is explicitly forced to be String
    Dim ValueArr() As String
    ValueArr = Split(VALUES, " ")
    
    'Bubble Sort - Loop until no further changes are neccesary
    Dim IsFinished As Boolean
    While Not IsFinished
        IsFinished = True
        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(ValueArr) To UBound(ValueArr) - 1
            ' The > operator is comparing strings alphabetically because the two values are String
            If ValueArr(i) > ValueArr(i + 1) Then
                'Swap
                Dim tmp As String
                tmp = ValueArr(i)
                ValueArr(i) = ValueArr(i + 1)
                ValueArr(i + 1) = tmp
                IsFinished = False
            End If
        Next
    Wend
    
    Debug.Print Join(ValueArr, " ")
    'Outputs "10 1010 11 111 2 201 300100 3210"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Sort Delimited Cells

```
=LET(Data,A2:C14,delSplit,",",delJoin," ",
MAP(Data,LAMBDA(cell,
    IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(delJoin,1,SORT(TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(cell,delSplit,,1)),,,1)),""))))
```

[image]

To create your own `LAMBDA` function, e.g. `SortDelimited`, in the `Name Manager` you could use the following...

```
=LAMBDA(Data,delSplit,delJoin,
MAP(Data,LAMBDA(cell,
    IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(delJoin,1,SORT(TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(cell,delSplit)),,,1)),""))))
```

when you would use it anywhere in the workbook with e.g. the simple...

```
=SortDelimited(A2:C14,","," ")
```